# How could we optimize following query without using virtual table concept

Tags: sql, db2

following is a query with using virtual concept but i want its optimized form without using **"virtual table"**  concept.

```
 with TEMP AS
          (

          Select RN from                                                            
          (                                                                         
          SELECT TCTITL,                                                            
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TCTITL asc ) AS RN FROM PVTC ORDER BY        
          TCTITL asc                                                                
          )T 

          WHERE ((TCTITL >= 'AAPS  ' ))                                             
          ORDER BY TCTITL asc fetch first row only  )  

          , mytab as
          (

          Select * from
          (                                                           
         ( SELECT TCTITL, TCEDUR, TCSTZF, TCTTLE, TCLSHN, TCCEQ3,                  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TCTITL asc ) AS RN                           
         FROM PVTC ORDER BY TCTITL asc  )                                          
          ) Q

          ,  TEMP where Q.RN                                                     
          between (TEMP.RN + 0) and ( TEMP.RN + 3)                                  
          )
          select * from mytab
```

Note: I have table with result say 1 to 10 but i want result between two pointer only say 3 to 10. this is the objective of this query.

**Update:** I have five records and i want to select record based on Row_Number 2  between the range 1 t0 5.(where 1,2,3,4,5 showing Row_number )

```
   col1    col2    col3 
    a   b   c   
    a1  b1  c1  
    -------------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------
    a5  b5  c5
```

Comment: It is hard to optimize without execution plan.

Comment: @Vash ok i am updating the post

Comment: You would be advised to include example data, desired results, and an english desription of what you are trying to achieve.  This code seems, ummm, more convoluted that it may need to be...

Comment: By "virtual table" do you mean the common table expression (CTE)? In general, this will lead to more readable queries.

Comment: As Dems said, you need to explain in english what results you want.  We can't "optimize" without knowing what the desired task is.  The note at the end of your post doesn't qualify.  What are you trying to accomplish in a real-world sense?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you explained why you don't want common table expressions.  There is nothing un-optimized about them.  At worst, they are just a clearer way to write your query.  At best, they actually increase performance when they allow you to do away with duplicate sub-selects.

Comment: "I just want to fetch data on the basis of record number that i provide."  Sorry, but this is still not clear.  What is a "record number"?  Is it just a row number?  And, what exact data do you want to fetch when a certain record number is given?  Please put some more thought into describing what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you merely want to fetch the first four rows where `tctitl >= 'AAPS  '`, as well as a row number that describes their rank in the table.  If so, I think this would do the trick:

```
select * from (
        select pvtc.*, row_number() over (order by tctitl) as rn from pvtc 
    )
    where (tctitl >= 'AAPS  ' )                                             
    order by tctitl
    fetch first four rows only;
```